# Generate dates between a range based on parameters SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following data in my input table

```
warehouse      start_date              end date        distance
AB11           1990-12-01              2020-10-23      10.2
AB11           2020-10-23              NULL            2.5
```

Expect output

```
warehouse      run_date          distance         
AB11           1990-12-01        10.2
AB11           1990-12-02        10.2
...  generate days until the end date
AB11           1990-10-22        10.2
AB11           2020-10-23        2.5
...   +3650 days (10 years)
AB11           2030-10-22        2.5
```

In the input, if the end date is defined,then I would like to generate dates from the start date upto the end date. 
If the end date is NULL, then I would like to generate dates from start date upto 10 years later.
I have tried level and other suggestions but I still have not been able to solve this.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Actually I am using Redshift (code language very similar to Oracle)

Comment: . . Redshift is not at all similar to Oracle and has its own database tag.  You should tag your questions correctly.